Shimano GRX600 levers and hose
I have Shimano GRX600 levers and Tektro T275 hydraulic disc brakes. According to my research, the grx600 series uses bh90 series hoses. My question is that can I use any bh90 hose with the right olive in this system? Or do I have to use only the sm-bk90-jk-ssr hose? Thanks.

BH90 hose is BH90 hose. I'm not sure what the -ssr means, but -jk refers to J-kit, which just means the system comes with some plastic stoppers to make the installation a little more plug and play. Functionally the same once installed though. This Reddit thread asks a similar question. To quote the top comment:

The hose itself is identical as long as it is BH90. The other critical parts are the brass olive that goes around the hose and the barbed insert must be the silver one not the brass colored one. The rest of the kit is just various fittings that would be specific to road brake levers as opposed to MTB brake levers. If you already have the fittings, no need to replace those - they'll work with the replacement hose. Again - you just need to replace the hose, the silver barbed inserts, and the brass olives on both ends of the hose.

The important part is that you get the right fittings to use. Mismatching Tektro and Shimano can be awkward because they use different hose outer diameters--Tektro is designed for 5.5mm hose, Shimano for 5.0mm. It should work with all Shimano barbs and olives, but there's always some risk involved with using a 5.0mm hose with a caliper fitting designed for a 5.5mm one.
